# Principal Component Analysis - function object has no attribute 'loc'

Tags: dataframe, pca

I'm trying to separate the features for normalisation in order to carry out PCA on a cancer dataset.
However, every time i try to separate the features using x = df.loc[:, features].values, i get the following error?
i've searched it and still confused as to what it is i'm supposed to do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpOBF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line `df = df.dropna` to `df = df.dropna()`.

Because you want to call the method that drops missing values on your dataframe. But if you write it without the parentheses, you are instead assigning the method itself to `df`, so `df` is no longer a dataframe, hence it has no `loc` attribute, so the error message is correct.